# Api,Registration/ Authorezation

Tags: json, swift, api

Необходимо сделать регистрацию и авторизациюю по api https://bla.com:3000/api/signup
считываться из текстового поля (вводит пользователь), данные должны отправляться вот именно в таком виде
{
 user:{
        email:email,
        password: pwd,
        name:name
}
}

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Не вопрос, а помощь прошу, как это реализовать, если можно с примером кода

Comment: а что именно не получается, сделать запрос в нужном виде, или вообще весь запрос не знаете как писать?

Comment: Да, проблема именно с запросом(((
Я бы скинул сюда код, но места не хватает 
вот пытаюсь в таком виде сделать, но дальше он ругается
let postString =  ["user" : ["email":username, "password": password, "name": usermainname]]
на это -> 
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

Comment: Выдает вот такую вот ошибку 
 Value of type '[String : Dictionary<String, String>]' has no member 'data'

Comment: @KonstantinOvcharenko Добро пожаловать на [ru.so] В тексте вопросе должен быть минимальный пример для воспроизведения и/или текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы ответить на твой вопрос нет совершенно никаких данных, GET или POST или PUT метод ожидает сервер? Какие данные надо передать в хэдере? В каком виде предполагается ответ сервера?
Напишу наиболее распространенный в моей практике вариант регистрации с POST методом, Swift 3:

```
    func serverRequest (email: String, password: String, name: String, completion: @escaping (_ responseObject: AnyObject?) -> (Void)) -> URLSessionTask?  {
let session = URLSession.shared

// задаем url запроса
let url = URL(string: "https://bla.com:3000/api/signup")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

//наиболее часто встречающиеся настройки
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


request.httpMethod = "POST" // или GET, PUT

let x: UInt = 0

// создаем дикшионари с данными
let userDictionary: NSDictionary = ["user": ["email": email, "password": password, "name": name]]

// сериализуем данные в JSON
    let requestBody : Data
    do {
        requestBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userDictionary, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: x))

    } catch {
        print("request NSJSONSerialization error in dataWithJSONObject")
        completion(nil)
        return nil
    }

// присваиваем данные в тело запроса
    request.httpBody = requestBody

// отправляем на сервер
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
    data, response, error in

    // ловим глобальные ошибки (нет сети например)
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {
        completion(data as AnyObject?)
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    // обрабатываем ответ сервера
    let responseObject: Any!
    do {
        responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.init(rawValue: x))

    } catch {
        // раз не JSON перводим в строчку и читаем (может HTML или строка)
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
        print("error in JSONObjectWithData: \(responseString) \(response)")
        completion(responseString as AnyObject?)
        return
    }
    // возвращаем полученный ответ
    completion(responseObject as AnyObject?)
    return
})
task.resume()
return task }
```

использовать:

```
   serverRequest(email: "some@adress.com", password: "123456789", name: "Ivan") { (responseObject) -> (Void) in
// используй полученный responseObject исходя из того что ты ожидаешь в ответе

//если например мы бы ждали в ответе дикшионари с токеном по ключу "authToken" мы бы его распарсили так
if let responcDict = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
    if let token = responcDict["authToken"] as? String {
        // как-то используем полученный токен
    } else { print("responseDict have no authToken") }
} else { print("responseObject not a Dictionary") }}
```

UPD: вот применительно к твоему вводу данных обращение через выше описаный метод. Проверку что строки не пустые я написал, но возможно в зависимости от требований сервера тебе придется проверять корректно ли юзер ввел данные, email ли и телефон он там ввёл а не бессмысленный набор символов.

```
           IBAction func buttonSignIn(_ sender: UIButton){

        //  проверяем что во всех строках есть данные
        guard let userName: String = buttonNameTxt.text else { return }
        guard let userEmail: String = buttonEmailTxt.text else { return }
        guard let password: String = buttonPwdTxt.text else { return }

        // обращаемся к написанному выше методу

        serverRequest(email: userEmail, password: password, name: userName) { (responseObject) -> (Void) in
            // используй полученный responseObject исходя из того что ты ожидаешь в ответе
            // не забывай что ответ придет асинхронно
        }
    }
```

Comment: Все верно, через post, только нужно необходимо передавать значения из строк, которые заполняет пользователь
IBAction func buttonSignUP(_ sender: UIButton){
class SignUp: UIViewController {
IBOutlet weak var buttonNameTxt: UITextField!
IBOutlet weak var buttonEmailTxt: UITextField!
IBOutlet weak var buttonPwdTxt: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad() 
}
IBAction func buttonSignIn(_ sender: UIButton) {   
let username = buttonNameTxt.text!
let useremail = buttonEmailTxt.text!
let password = buttonPwdTxt.text!
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: добавил апдейт с применением к твоему случаю